# Role of coefficients in model selection for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, classification, confidence-interval, roc, auc

I have a model that I am using to predict mortality and it gives me an AUC of 0.799. The `R` code that I am using would look something like this:

```
fit <- glm(mortality ~ Age + Sex + ASA + Wndclass, data=sepsis, family=binomial)
```

I am calculating my AUC using `ROCR`:

```
library(ROCR)
fit.pred <- predict(fit)
sepsis.pred <- prediction(fit.pred, mortality[,1])
sepsis.perf <- performance(sepsis.pred, "auc")
```

Calling `sepsis.perf` gives me:

```
An object of class "performance"
Slot "x.name":
[1] "None"

Slot "y.name":
[1] "Area under the ROC curve"

Slot "alpha.name":
[1] "none"

Slot "x.values":
list()

Slot "y.values":
[[1]]
[1] 0.7990628


Slot "alpha.values":
list()
```

So far I have conluded that this model isn't too bad as a classifier. However when I look at the coefficients, especially the 95% CI, of the logistic regression model I get some strange results:

```
(Intercept)                   8.248484e-03  3.394696e-02
SEXfemale                     9.037957e-01  1.325291e+00
SEXNULL                      3.864079e-204 5.780619e+192
Age                           1.026437e+00  1.043482e+00
ASACLAS2-Mild Disturb        1.408200e-220 3.478857e+229
ASACLAS3-Severe Disturb      1.769693e-220 4.367441e+229
ASACLAS4-Life Threat         3.596686e-220 8.876357e+229
ASACLAS5-Moribund            8.561098e-220 2.113924e+230
ASACLASNULL                  2.702457e-219 6.747396e+230
ASACLASNone assigned         1.513924e-219 3.793387e+230
WNDCLAS2-Clean/Contaminated   9.281083e-01  1.897956e+00
WNDCLAS3-Contaminated         8.968408e-01  1.604651e+00
WNDCLAS4-Dirty/Infected       5.114258e-01  8.718848e-01
```

What bothers me here is the 95% CI for ASA class, which is ridiculous. However when I take it out of my model, the AUC drops to 0.78, and clinically, the ASA (American Society of Anesthesiologists) classification is often used to stratify patients into low to high risk for mortality in the perioperative period.

So my question is, given these results of the 95% CI, should I exclude ASA class? If not, how should I interpret ASA class in view of my results? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suspect multicollinearity. The confidence interval of `SEXNULL` is also extremely wide. Could you explain how `SEXNULL` and `ASA` are related? The `R` [package `rms`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) has a function called `vif` that calculates the variance inflation factors which are used to spot multicollinearity. It works with a `glm`. It may be helpful if you posted the output of `vif(fit)`.

Comment: how big is your dataset - could the large se be a symptom of separation. You could try rerunning using logistf (firths regression) instead of glm and see if the se are better behaved.

Comment: The dataset has an n=4200